# Getting Error: uuid is not declared configurable while using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am getting an error while spying using jasmine and typescript for an angular project.

Here is my code:

```
import * as utils from 'app/shared/utils';

it('sample test',
fakeAsync(() => {
  const uuidFunc = jasmine.createSpy('uuid').and.returnValue('12345');
  spyOnProperty(utils, 'uuid', 'get').and.returnValue(uuidFunc);
  ......
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Error: uuid is not declared configurable
```

The uuid function:

```
export function uuid(): string {
   const bytes = new Uint32Array(4);
   return bytes;
 }
```

This was working till Angular 8 and I have upgraded to Angular 9 and it has started complaining

Comment: try 

`utils.uuid = uuidFunc;`

Comment: @gouravarora That has not worked. I am still getting the same issue